# What is the longest byte instruction possible in 8088?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I'm making a minimalistic assembler for 8088. I would like to know what is the longest possible byte instruction combination?

At the moment, the longest instruction I found is 6 bytes.:

```
add word [0134], 0032
```

which translates to

```
81 06 34 01 32 00
```

Is there anything longer than 6 bytes?

---

Also a Sidequestion, I understand the whole 6 bytes completely except for the 4th byte.

like for example:

1st byte means: add with 16bit of immediate data

2nd byte means: Base pointer + displacement command

3rd byte means: the displacement

5-6 byte means: the 16bit data

But I have no idea what does the 4th byte means, specifically the "1" value.

What does that mean?

Comment: Isn't `34 01` just a 16-bit address?

Comment: It shouldn't be unless I'm interpreting this wrongly, the 8088 manual says this: (2nd byte) mod 0 0 0 r/m
since 06 translates to 00000110 r/m = 110. It says that If r/m = 110. Then EA = (BP) + Displacement. So I assume 100 is base pointer, 34 is displacement. the 4th byte is still a mystery to me

Comment: There are infinite instructions on 8088, they are non-interruptable when executed.  Just fill 64Kbytes with segment prefix (e.g., CS:).  Processor will never stop executing this very-long-instruction, as address would wrap at 64K boundary :)

Comment: chepner already answered that 34 01 comes from the 0134  and 32 00 comes from the 0032 in the instruction.

Comment: > longer than 6 bytes? - Use an alternate segment register (like es:) which will generate a prefix byte.

Comment: You could add a segment override to reach seven bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The longest byte the 8088 supports is 4-bytes for word size arithmetic type functions that you've already identified.  These 4-byte instructions do not contain the 3rd byte displacement you suggest. The '1' refers to the trailing bit of the first 1 byte, not an entire byte in itself.

Reference:
[The 8088 Data Sheet - Page 26-30](http://datasheets.chipdb.org/Intel/x86/808x/datashts/8088/231456-006.pdf)